Terraform module override new attributes
In our existing infra, we calling version 7.4.0 of the following module in our own module.
terraform-google-modules/vm/google//modules/instance_template
When we try and upgrade to latest version 11.1.0, some new attributes like enable_nested_virtualization, total_egress_bandwidth_tier are getting added which are forcing the resource replacement(destroy and create).
Is there a way to handle these new attributes so that they don't force replacement? Also, these new attributes are optional as per the module documentation but still they're getting added.
We tried adding these new attributes to terraform code and then run the plan, but as these are new attributes, we're still getting force replacement message.

It's unusual to jump between major module versions. You should probably perform a step-by-step upgrade from 7.x.x to 11.x.x. Since most of the modules are using semantic versioning, you need to understand how that works. Changes in the leading number means there are usually some big changes involved.
If you go to releases, you will also see a list of changes in the newer module versions. For example, the version 8.0.0 has breaking changes. Each of the newer versions (>8.x.x) has some breaking changes. So what you would usually do is perform an upgrade to 8.0.0 and then proceed from there to the newer module versions.

Thank you for the guidance on upgrading process. Is there a way to handle these new "optonal" module attributes from forcing the resource replacement? something like ignore_changes for modules? There should be an option provided to suppress new attributes(atleast for the optional ones) from force replacing resources.

I don't know how GCP APIs work, but in general, the optional arguments should be set to whatever represents the default value. However, if the module is using a new and updated provider version, in that case some of the resources might have changed along the way. The best way is to read through the upgrade documentation if it exists as mentioned.
